# Can I use a US Xbox live while I live in Morocco?

Tags: xbox-network, xbox-one

The title says it all. I want to be able to play multiplayer games and have more freedom downloading region restricted DLCs and games.

It's worth mentioning that Morocco doesn't have an official Live membership subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I live in Luxembourg which isn't officially supported by live either, yet, I have an Xbox Live account tied to the UK marketplace and it works fine.

However, there are a few restrictions. You will not be able to access IP-fenced content as your IP does not match your marketplace region. You may want to use VPN to work around this issue.

You will not be able to use a credit card or Paypal account registered outside of your marketplace region to make purchases. Therefore, you will need to rely on local currency cards and localized Live subscription redeemable codes.

Furthermore, please be aware that many interfaces on the console will change to reflect your marketplace region. The US will be English but there may be some unexpected changes when switching to regions who feature non-English marketplace languages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
Since I have an Xbox One. IP-fenced content will mostly be available to me, as I've read in multiple threads.

I guess the best solution is to buy US Live subscription and credit redeemable codes.

Comment: From my personal experience, I would suggest choosing a marketplace based on your language preferences first, then content, and lastly stability of currency. Keep in mind that if your local currency's exchange rate compared to the dollar drops/rises, your ability to purchase content will be affected too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I spent the last couple of hours comparing Xbox marketplaces and MAD (Moroccan Dirham) currency exchange rates. It seems that the cheapest place to buy from is the US marketplace, as the currency exchange rate between MAD and USD is lower than Euro or GBP for example. not to mention that I prefer English as a UI and multiplayer language. again, thanks for your reply, it really helped.